# SignalR LongPolling multiple Groups.Add for a single client Exception

Tags: c#, javascript, signalr

I've been struggling with this one for a while. We're using the latest SignalR 2.0.3. The problem happens when we add to multiple SignalR groups. The exception is only thrown when multiple adds happen from the same connectionId with different group names. The exception is only thrown if the LongPolling transport is selected. The exception is only thrown if you add to 6+ unique group names, 5 or less and it works fine.

Here's a simplified example:

Index.cshtml:

```
    @model Int32?
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js")"
    type="text/javascript" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")" type="text/javascript"/>
    </head>

    <script>
        _testHub = $.connection.testHub;
        _testHub.client.sayHello = sayHello;
        $.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'longPolling' })
            .done(function() {
                addAllGroups();
            });

        function sayHello(aMessage, aGroupName) {
            console.info("GroupName: " + aGroupName 
    + " Message Sent:" + aMessage);
        };

        function addAllGroups() {
            for (var i = 0; 
              i < @(Model.HasValue ? Model.Value : 1 ); i++) {
                  addToGroupAndBroadcast(i);
            }
        };

        function addToGroupAndBroadcast(aGroupName) {
            _testHub.server.addToGroupAndBroadcast(aGroupName)
                .fail(function (desc) {
                    console.info("Error: " + desc);
                });
        };

    </script>
```

SignalRTestController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;


namespace Instrumar.ProductionDashboard.Controllers
{
    public class SignalRTestController : Controller
    {
        #region Public Members

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View((int?)Convert.ToInt32(Request.Url.Segments[4]));
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

TestHub.cs:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;


namespace Instrumar.ProductionDashboard.Hubs
{
    public class TestHub : Hub
    {
        #region Public Members

        public void AddToGroupAndBroadcast(string aGroupName)
        {
            GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TestHub>().Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, aGroupName).Wait();
            Clients.Group(aGroupName).sayHello("Hello", aGroupName);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRChat.Startup))]
namespace SignalRChat
{

    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var lHubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration {EnableDetailedErrors = true};
            app.UseErrorPage();
            app.MapSignalR(lHubConfiguration);
        }
    }
}
```

The controller takes an integer as input which is the number of Add's to do. For example, if you call:

http://yourip.com/WebApplicationName/SignalRTest/Index/1 one Groups.Add **works fine**
http://yourip.com/WebApplicationName/SignalRTest/Index/2 two Groups.Add **works fine**
http://yourip.com/WebApplicationName/SignalRTest/Index/3 three Groups.Add **works fine**
http://yourip.com/WebApplicationName/SignalRTest/Index/4 four Groups.Add **works fine**
http://yourip.com/WebApplicationName/SignalRTest/Index/5 five Groups.Add **works fine**
http://yourip.com/WebApplicationName/SignalRTest/Index/6 six Groups.Add **broken**
http://yourip.com/WebApplicationName/SignalRTest/Index/7 seven Groups.Add **broken**
http://yourip.com/WebApplicationName/SignalRTest/Index/8 eight Groups.Add **broken**
http://yourip.com/WebApplicationName/SignalRTest/Index/9 nine Groups.Add **broken**
http://yourip.com/WebApplicationName/SignalRTest/Index/10 ten Groups.Add **broken**

...

When I say broken, I get back a "System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException" in TestHub.cs on the line waiting for the task to complete. Everything works fine with ServerSentEvents but for LongPolling the problem exists. What am I doing wrong? Can I not have more than 5 SignalR groups with LongPolling? Help me! :)

---

Update: Putting a 1 millisecond sleep using setTimeout between clientside calls fixed the problem. This seems to alleviate the number of pending connections in the network tab. Maybe something happens to the ability to add to a group when you reach the single browser connection limit. It would be nice to know exactly why this doesn't work though.

Comment: Firstly, I am not seeing the tie between your version of VS and why you can't upgrade to the latest version of SignalR which is open source.  Secondly, when I implmented SignalR, I didn't require any of the code that you've posted.  Where did you get the code you are using?  Did you write it yourself?

Comment: I was under the impression from google searching that SignalR versions greater than 1.2.1 required .net 4.5 and Visual Studio 2010 did not support that. One person mentioned you could rebuild SignalR yourself from source but we thought that option was risky.

Comment: Yes I wrote that code myself. This js file was a lot simpler initially. We followed the microsoft SignalR guide down to a tee but when we released our software into the wild we had issues. It had to be modified due to real world exceptional cases. Our software runs on a website that is shown 24/7 over an internal network with hundreds of signalR updates a second. Some of these issues may have been due to the older version of SignalR we were using (1.0.1 initially) and we may have fixed things that are no longer bugs in the newest version of SignalR.

Comment: Additionally, some of the code in the JS file above is application specific. I tried to reduce the JS file to the minimum keeping everything relevant to this question present.

Comment: You should probably post more code related to your `Service.ClientServices.Registration.Register` method and what runtime values are passed to `DashboardHub.Register(String aToken)`.  Can you actively debug and see the exception or does it just get logged into a file? It looks like there is a related issue that has been fixed here https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1155.  If that's it, you would have to pull the code and recompile your own DLL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have more than 5 groups with long-polling, but you'll have to work around the connection issue by not adding to groups in a loop.

The task returned from `Groups.Add` only completes when it receives an ACK message from the message bus indicating that the message for the client (notifying it of the group add) has been sent. 
If there are more than 5 (or whatever number is enforced by the browser) pending AJAX requests tied to the `addToGroupAndBroadcast` call from the client, then the message to the client can't be sent. If you attach a done callback to your client call:

```
_testHub.server.addToGroupAndBroadcast(groupName).done(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
```

you'll see the first call completes almost immediately.

This is when the first Groups.Add call returns. The message to `sayHello` doesn't get sent anymore because it would require another open polling request, which the client is creating, but won't get handled since there are multiple other pending requests from the client that have been enqueued first (and those are all waiting on `addToGroupAndBroadcast` to complete).

So after the first call to Groups.Add, the server is unable to send anything to the client, the MessageHub can't send its ACK which would resolve the remaining `Groups.Add` promises.
As a result, the `TaskCanceledException` gets thrown for those Tasks because of a timeout.

As a work-around, I would suggest to create a hub method which accepts an array of group names:

```
public async Task AddToGroups(string[] names)
{
    foreach (var name in names)
    {
        await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, name);
        Clients.Group(name).sayHello("Hello", name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a related issue that has been fixed here https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1155.  If that's it, you would have to pull the code and recompile your own DLL. Also, your bug could also be caused by a timeout.

This could also be relevant to your problem:

> ... because the connection id that you are trying to
>   remove might no longer be available. In that case,
>   TaskCanceledException is thrown after the request times out.

Ref. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/working-with-groups

Comment: It seems like this could be related. We just received VS 2013 today so i'm in the process of building the project against .net 4.5 with the latest version of SignalR and if the bug is fixed the bounty is yours.

Comment: Good luck.  If possible, I would try to avoid asynchronous methods such as `.Wait()`

Comment: Unfortunately the problem was still reproducable with the latest version of SignalR 2.0.3 and .net 4.5.

Comment: So, it must be related to your specific code.  Any thoughts on removing the `.Wait()`?  I don't have any such method in my implementation.  If, in fact, you are using the latest version, could you now just follow the latest documentation and "recreate" your current functionality this time; however, in the "recommended" way?

Comment: I'm hesitant to remove the functionality the way it is until I can guarantee the bugs we saw in the field are fixed. The reason why we have to wait on the Groups.Add is because there is a postcondition that relies on the client being added to the group later in the register function. The way it works is a client is added to the group, then provided initial data, all in the same function. I could rewrite this a different way but i'd rather get at the bottom of this problem. I've began downloading the SignalR source to find out why the Task is being cancelled through the debugger.

Comment: It looks like the exception no longer occurs after removing the .Wait(). The "problem" I might have now is that right after I call Clients.Group.Add();, I immediately call Clients.Group(groupName).myClientFunction();. My question is, can I guarantee that the client I added will receive the "myClientFunction" call? It seems like there's an inherent race condition there. But maybe signalR handles this ordering?

Comment: Unfortunately I just read from http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/working-with-groups, that "If you want to add a client to a group and immediately send a message to the client by using the group, you have to make sure that the Groups.Add method finishes first."

Comment: Why is SignalR cancelling the add to group anyways? If I knew that I think I could figure it out on my own. Is it a timeout or something? How can I get at the underlying exception? I tried referencing the source code and debugging Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core and Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb but still wasn't able to see why it was getting cancelled.

Comment: I am a little confused - can't you simply call a linear method to register your group, then broadcast your message to your group?  Why does there need to be any asynchronous behavior?

Comment: I don't think there needs to be any asynchronous behaviour necessarily. All we need is to guarantee a user is in a group before sending the group a message. If there's a better way of doing this than waiting on the task I'm open to suggestions :)

Comment: If that is how you want it to work, then can you try checking to see if the client's ID (which I assume you are using the user's ID) is in the group, if so, then send the message to the group, as outlined here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/404662/SignalR-Group-Notifications ?  Look for the method `GetClients(string group)`

Comment: We don't want to check to see if the groupName is added. We want to add to a group, then immediatly send a message to that group. We want everyone to receive that message, including the connectionId we just added to the group.

Comment: I rewrote the question in a simpler form reproducing the problem without having to reconnect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55923/discussion-between-adam-and-user1477388).

Comment: The code I gave you gets all CLIENTS of a group, not the group name.  That's where it says, `return ctx.Clients[group];` which you could then check to see if your users ID is contained therein.  If not, add them (or what a few seconds) and try to add them again, then check again.  It's not ideal but I do not know the specifics of your project.